# Sending livetail output to an http endpoint

Tags: curl, stream, tail, sumologic

I am using [livetail-cli](https://github.com/SumoLogic/livetail-cli) provided by sumologic.

I am trying send the livetail output to an http endpoint. But it shows connection time out error after some time.

The command which i am using is

```
while IFS= read -r newline; do echo $newline |  curl -XPOST --data-binary $0 http://localhost:9090 -H Content-Type:application/json  ; done < <(./livetail _sourceCategory="x")
```

What is the best way to achieve this so that the connection persists?Although the sumologic api mentions about the session timeout after 30min of inactivity. But i am sure that the logs would be continuously coming from the source.

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm not sure I understand what you're doing. Sumo Logic's livetail-cli tool is to view a live tail of logs that are already coming into Sumo Logic. In order to stream logs into Sumo Logic, you just need a collector, or you need to post to an HTTP source directly.

Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I want to send these live-tail logs to an HTTP source. Since live-tail is almost realtime, i want to go by this approach. Is there anything else in sumo-logic which is real-time . Main goal is to send these logs which are coming into sumologic to our HTTP source. I don't have control over the source from which sumologic is getting the logs .

Comment: Ah I see - Sorry, I thought you meant a Sumo Logic HTTP source. Let me answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Sumo Logic's live tail/live tail CLI wasn't intended to stream logs to be forwarded on to other systems.

For this you should either [forward it directly from the collector](https://help.sumologic.com/Manage/Data-Forwarding/Configure-Data-Forwarding-for-Installed-Collectors) or [forward it to an S3 bucket](https://help.sumologic.com/Manage/Data-Forwarding/Configure-Data-Forwarding-from-Sumo-Logic-to-S3) and set up a [Lambda function to then forward it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) on to your other HTTP source.